# overfull \hbox error in a table and text, not sure what is wrong, any help?

Tags: tables, text

I used the following code for my table, and the contents are not too long, I am not sure why I get this error message, though the compilation looks fine ...

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}  
% Include any extra LaTeX packages required
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  % Use the "Natbib" style for the references in the Bibliography
\usepackage{verbatim}  
\usepackage{vector}  
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true}  
    \begin{table}[h!]
    \caption{Optimized cycling conditions.\label{Optimized cycling conditions.}}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c c c c|} 
     \hline
     \large{\textbf{Step}} & \large{\textbf{Time}} & \large{\textbf{Temperature}} & \large{\textbf{Comment}}  \\ [0.5ex] 
     \hline\hline
     Initial heat activation & 5 min & 95°C & Activates DNA polymerase  \\ 
     \hline
     3 step cycling: total 35 cycles     & 15s &95°C & Denaturing    \\ 
     \hline
      & 15s & 60°C &Annealing \\
     \hline
      & 10s & 72°C &Extension \\
     \hline
       & 2 min & 72°C & Final extension \\
     \hline
     & $\infty$ & 72°C& holding \\
     \hline
     \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

For the text I am getting similar error msg, the text that I used is mentioned below-

```
The following day, XX was performed to check the identity of ABC. Firstly, the XX to digest the  were selected from SMC web tool \texttt{(https://www.promega.com.au/resources/tools/retool/)} (For IFN$\beta$, XbaI+ Hind III; for NF-$\kappa$B, Bgl II+ Xho I). The XX and their references are below-
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the packages you use. This helps others to reproduce the outout and warning messages you get.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Where did you get the `Thesis` document class from?

Comment: I am using overleaf thesis template for "monash University"

Comment: Is it an error or a warning? If I compile your code (after adding missing commands), I found no errors.

Comment: an overfull box isn't an error it is just awarning that tex could not find a good place to break the line, so if you want help with a particular warning you need to provide an example that can be run to generate the warning as it depends on the exact wording and exact size of the space into which you are placing the text.

Comment: I provided the exact thing I am using for the table, did you mean I add the text here as well (as I was having this warning for both the table and the text)?

Answer (score 2):

Since you claim that the table is not too wide for the page, but you nevertheless get the overfull box warning: If you add `\usepackage{showframe} \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}` to the preamble of your document, you get a set of red lines that indicate the text area and the margins. As you can see from the following screenshot, your table indeed is too wide. Also, the url protrudes into the margin causing the warning message you observe.

[image]

Here is version of your code in which I changed the layout of the table in order to make sure its fits into the available space. For the url, I used `\url` instead ot `\texttt`:

[image]

Here is a compilable MWE under the assumption, that the following template is used: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/monash-thesis-template-latex/fcjzjygysncw

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}  
% Include any extra LaTeX packages required
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  % Use the "Natbib" style for the references in the Bibliography
\usepackage{verbatim}  
\usepackage{vector}  
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}



\mainmatter  
\pagestyle{fancy} 

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Optimized cycling conditions.\label{Optimized cycling conditions.}}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llcl} 
 \toprule
 Step & Time & Temperature & Comment  \\ 
 \midrule
 Initial heat activation          & \qty{5}{\min} & \qty{95}{\celsius} & Activates DNA polymerase  \\ \addlinespace 
 3 step cycling: total 35 cycles  & \qty{15}{\s}  & \qty{95}{\celsius} & Denaturing                \\ \addlinespace 
                                  & \qty{15}{\s}  & \qty{60}{\celsius} & Annealing                 \\ \addlinespace 
                                  & \qty{10}{\s}  & \qty{72}{\celsius} & Extension                 \\ \addlinespace 
                                  & \qty{2}{\min} & \qty{72}{\celsius} & Final extension           \\ \addlinespace 
                                  & $\infty$      & \qty{72}{\celsius} & holding                   \\
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

The following day, XX was performed to check the identity of ABC. Firstly, the XX to digest the  were selected from SMC web tool \url{(https://www.promega.com.au/resources/tools/retool/)} (For IFN$\beta$, XbaI+ Hind III; for NF-$\kappa$B, Bgl II+ Xho I). The XX and their references are below-

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's much more helpful to have a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497) that we can copy, paste, and compile without needing to download non-standard classes or packages.

Your table's warning comes from the first line.  Look into how to have multiple lines in a table cell.  Your text's warning (probably) comes from using `\texttt` to typeset a url.  Since your class loads hyperref anyway, just use `\url`.  ("Probably" is because it's almost impossible to diagnose a overfull hbox without knowing the exact text that was typed in and "XX" is not what you have in your document.)

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can ignore this error unless it really does go out of the page. I get it a lot but when the compilation is fine I just ignore it. Unless it affects the compilation itself, you don't need to worry. Also, when you are posting a question, there is an option to write code so it would be so much nicer to look at it.

Comment: It's not a great idea to ignore errors, they may cause problems you don't immediately see

Comment: I will follow your advice thank you, and next time will add the codes in the 'code option', I need to find where this option is, I probably overlooked it, my apologies